# Elixir and mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, elixir, aggregate

I have setup a mongodb with one collection that has this structure:

```
{ "_id" : "some_id", "city" : { "name" : "City1" }}
```

I've started a project with elixir 1.9.2 and phoenix and I've setup {:mongodb, "~> 0.5.1"}

I've already setup in phoenix some find queries already working, so my connection with mongodb from phoenix work just fine.

**Edit:**
Those are queries that already works for me:

```
def get_trip_list() do


{:ok, conn} = Mongo.start_link(url:"mongodb://localhost:27017/myaguila")

    cursor = Mongo.find(conn, "trip", %{})

    cursor
    |> Enum.to_list()
  end
```

```
def get_total_count() do
    {:ok, conn} = Mongo.start_link(url: "mongodb://localhost:27017/myaguila")
    cursor = Mongo.count(conn, "trip", %{})
    {:ok, total} = cursor
    {:total_trips, total}
  end
```

**But now I need to build a query with aggregation to count how many times appears each city and I really can't understand how to use the mongodb pipeline from phoenix**

I write a query directly in mongo's shell (I try and worked) this way:

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([{$group: {_id : "$city", count: {$sum: 1}}}])
```

and bring me those results:

> { "_id" : { "name" : "City1" }, "count" : 212 }
>
> { "_id" : { "name" : "City2" }, "count" : 1200 }
>
> { "_id" : { "name" : "City3" }, "count" : 789 }
>
> { "_id" : { "name" : "City4" }, "count" : 540 }
>
> { "_id" : { "name" : "City5" }, "count" : 333 }

So I need to translate this mongo query to elixir language.

(Don't know much about it but I see I dont use Ecto)

That's the same expected result in elixir.

This is the library's documentation

https://hexdocs.pm/mongodb/readme.html#contributing

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution:

`Mongo.aggregate(pid, "trip", [%{"$group" => %{ "_id" => "$city.name", "count" => %{ "$sum" => 1}}}])`

I was missing the square brackets before the first level map.

Thanks to the interested ones.

Answer (score 0):

Look :)

```
db.cities.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { name: "$city.name" },
             count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

Result in mongodb query

```
{ "_id" : { "name" : "City1" }, "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : { "name" : "City2" }, "count" : 2 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need the Phoenix's sintax. Up in the question I've already have the mongo query working.

Comment: There is no such thing as “Phoenix syntax” for queries. It’s “Ecto syntax” since _Phoenix_ does not implement any DB interoperation functionality on its own.

Comment: @Aleksei Matiushkin thanks for clarify, but I tnink I neither use Ecto, Im using this documentation and examples to work it https://hexdocs.pm/mongodb/readme.html#contributing

Comment: Ah; ok, then there is _mongodb adapter syntax_. Phoenix known literally nothing about DB level.